# Replace a string that has + in it in R

Tags: r, replace

I am trying to replace a string that includes `+` in it. However, the function I used failed to do that. Here is a sample dataset.

```
testdata <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                   v1 = c("A+B", "C","D"),
                   v2 = c("N","M","A+B"),
                   v3 = c("D","E","T"))

> testdata
  id  v1  v2 v3
1  1 A+B   N  D
2  2   C   M  E
3  3   D A+B  T
```

This function below did nothing.

```
testdata %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "A+B", "")))
```

I would like to remove `A+B` anywhere in the dataframe.

How can I reach the desired dataset below

```
> testdata
  id  v1  v2 v3
1  1  NA   N  D
2  2   C   M  E
3  3   D  NA  T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `+` with `\\`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

testdata |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_remove(., "A\\+B")))

#>   id v1 v2 v3
#> 1  1     N  D
#> 2  2  C  M  E
#> 3  3  D     T
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Use `na_if` if we want to replace a fixed string `"A+B"`

```
library(dplyr)
testdata <- testdata %>% 
     mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ na_if(.x,  "A+B")))
```

-output

```
testdata
 id   v1   v2 v3
1  1 <NA>    N  D
2  2    C    M  E
3  3    D <NA>  T
```

---

Or if we are checking for the `+` symbol

```
library(stringr)
testdata <- testdata %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.character),
     ~ case_when(str_detect(.x, fixed("+"), negate = TRUE) ~ .x)))
testdata
  id   v1   v2 v3
1  1 <NA>    N  D
2  2    C    M  E
3  3    D <NA>  T
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option to get rid of strings containing `+` would be:

```r
testdata[] <- lapply(testdata, \(x) ifelse(grepl("\\+", x), NA, x))
```

Result:

```r
testdata
#>   id   v1   v2 v3
#> 1  1 <NA>    N  D
#> 2  2    C    M  E
#> 3  3    D <NA>  T
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `+` is being interpreted as a regular expression, so you'll need to add two `\\` to escape that character. Then, you can use `str_replace`. Oh, and `mutate_all` has been superseded by `mutate(across(...))`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

testdata %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_replace(.x, "A\\+B", replacement = NA_character_))) 

#  id   v1   v2 v3
#1  1 <NA>    N  D
#2  2    C    M  E
#3  3    D <NA>  T
```